# How to assign particular ringtone to all contacts in particular group in android programmatically

Tags: android, ringtone, telephonymanager

I have assigned ringtone to all the contacts in particular group.please tell the telephony part like if someone calls from a number and that number is part of a group with a certain ringtone how do we provide this ringtone?